# Intellij javascript editor structure tab

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, editor

Intellij javascript editor. Click structure tab

```
No structure
```

It would be very very helpful. Did I miss anything? Why javascript editor has no structure for navigation?

Comment: What IDES version/edition do you use? Is it Ultimate or Community? Also, could you share screenshots illustrating the issue?

Comment: Intellij Version 2021.3.3 community.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA Community edition provides no support for JavaScript except for basic syntax highlighting provided with textmate bundles, see https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce. That's why advanced features like refactorings, code completion/navigaion and the Structure view are not available